# how to delete a contact data from Menu delete in ContextItemSelected listview android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-menu, android-context, android-cursor

I have tried this code but no data is lost from the listview when I clicked on the delete menu ContextItemSelected

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
            menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
            int id = menuinfo.position;
            deleteContact(id);
            populateContactList();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }


    public static boolean deleteContact(int id) {

        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
        Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=" + id, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                        String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                        ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri,ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=" + id, null);
                        return true;
                    }

                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

is there another way to delete a contact ?

Comment: "Trying" code does not help anyone. Know your concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on context item selected value, you also have to check in which listview item context menu is created , to do this you can write

```
if(itemID == 1)

{
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

int index_id = menuinfo.position;
deletedata(index_id);
```

in index_id you got the listview item on which context menu is created, after that you can fire query method and whatever you want to do with data. :)

Comment: I have changed it but ctx becomes undefined. how to define it?